# Drupal 8 change url to absolute

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to change my all internal url to absolute from relative as of now.

For e.g. my menu link urls are "/about" as so on I want this to be absolute url like xyz.com/about.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You need to change this directly to the cms menus or programmatically in your code?

Answer (score 2):

From the code that would be :

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$option = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url = Url::fromUserInput('/about', $option);
```

Comment: How about visa versa?